# Environment variables in VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Can I somehow define environment variables in VisualStudio?

Background:

I have two machines I am developing on, A and B.

On A, Boost is installed in "C:\boost"; on B, Boost is installed in "D:\boost".

I would like to somehow specify the include directory in the project configuration like

```
%(BoostDir)\include
```

and define BoostDir separately on each of the two machines.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx ?

Comment: So the idea is defining the environment variable as a Windows environment variable and then use it from within VS?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could even create a batch which sets the value dynamically: `@echo off / set YOURVARIABLE= / C:\VS\VS.exe`

Comment: Well, it DOES work perfectly. Thank you all. I was stuck in searching a way of setting a variable within VS and completely forgot about the Windows environment variables. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read environment variables and use them. Microsoft has this [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="FakeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FinalOutput>$(BIN_PATH)\myassembly.dll</FinalOutput>
    <ToolsPath Condition=" '$(ToolsPath)' == '' ">
        C:\Tools
    </ToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="FakeBuild">
    <Message Text="Building $(FinalOutput) using the tools at $(ToolsPath)..."/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

You can specify `BIN_PATH` either using a fixed environment variable that even survives reboots or set the value "on the fly" before calling Visual Studio:

```
@echo off
SET BIN_PATH=C:\Whatever
C:\Programs\VisualStudio\VS.exe
```

Take this as an example and adopt it to your needs.